# The things we do for love

Tags: cipher, steganography

A lawyer said to a peasant girl: "If you want to be my Girlfriend send me a note with your name and your favorite color so I can send you your favorite colored dress."

The peasant girl replied with a note:

> "Life is full of great things, and you happened to be one of them, not to mention please pardon my narrow vocab.
>   If my suitor is in love with me, and is truly entitled to win my heart, my name you will find in this verse, this is what you must first fulfil.
>   Nothing will break us apart if in here you can find my favorite color as well, and no, I'm not an expert or a love guru.
>   After all, it will all depend on you not losing me".

Comment: Definitely the letter doesn't show a narrow vocab, haha

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think her name is:

> Lina

Why:

> Because the start of each sentence spells that out.

Like this:

> "**L**ife is full of great things, and you happened to be one of them, not
>  to mention please pardon my narrow vocab. **I**f my suitor is in love with
>  me, and is truly entitled to win my heart, my name you will find in
>  this verse, this is what you must first fulfil. **N**othing will break us
>  apart if in here you can find my favorite color as well, and no, I'm
>  not an expert or a love guru. **A**fter all, it will all depend on you not
>  losing me".

And I think her favorite color is

> Blue

Why:

> The ending of each sentence before a period spells out Blue

Like this:

> "Life is full of great things, and you happened to be one of them, not
>  to mention please pardon my narrow voca**b**. If my suitor is in love
>  with me, and is truly entitled to win my heart, my name you will find
>  in this verse, this is what you must first fulfi**l**. Nothing will
>  break us apart if in here you can find my favorite color as well, and
>  no, I'm not an expert or a love gur**u**. After all, it will all
>  depend on you not losing m**e**".

Comment: If this is the answer, then steganography would be the right tag, not cryptography.

Comment: I agree, but I will be very surprised if it isn't the answer...

Comment: I'm not seeing it, could you add examples in your answer?

Comment: @dcfyj I added the examples for you.

Comment: Pretty good :D it is steganography indeed wasn't getting my thing clear xD